# Slow Performance of Ubuntu16.04 inside VMWare on laptop

Tags: boot, 16.04, performance, vmware-workstation

I installed ubuntu 16.04 on VMware Workstation recently. But since then ubuntu has been booting very slowly. It has been performing slowly as well.

My Laptop config is: Intel i7 core processor, 16gb ram, 2TB HD and 4Gb Nvidia Graphics card.

Allocated Space to ubuntu is 50Gb, Ram is 8Gb, Processors 2 and cores 2.
Still ubuntu frequently hangs in between.

Can someone please help ??

Result for systemd-analyze is:

```
Startup finished in 6.542s (kernel) + 17min 27.054s (userspace) = 17min 33.597s
```

Result for systemd-analyze blame is:

```
17min 17.980s apt-daily.service
      9.039s ModemManager.service
      7.676s accounts-daemon.service
      6.211s grub-common.service
      5.183s ondemand.service
      5.042s dev-sda1.device
      4.659s NetworkManager.service
      4.613s networking.service
      4.484s gpu-manager.service
      4.356s pppd-dns.service
      3.964s apparmor.service
      3.522s snapd.firstboot.service
      3.111s lightdm.service
      2.585s polkitd.service
      1.590s rsyslog.service
      1.550s irqbalance.service
      1.512s ssh.service
      1.364s systemd-logind.service
      1.352s avahi-daemon.service
      1.336s thermald.service
      1.269s apport.service
      1.132s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.118s keyboard-setup.service
      1.093s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.048s run-vmblock\x2dfuse.mount
       954ms console-setup.service
       938ms systemd-journald.service
       744ms speech-dispatcher.service
       724ms dev-mqueue.mount
       707ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       668ms alsa-restore.service
       643ms setvtrgb.service
       636ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       559ms systemd-udevd.service
       545ms dns-clean.service
       541ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       517ms plymouth-read-write.service
       509ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       473ms udisks2.service
       460ms upower.service
       422ms systemd-random-seed.service
       421ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       377ms dev-hugepages.mount
       373ms colord.service
       348ms ufw.service
       338ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       333ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       323ms resolvconf.service
       318ms systemd-localed.service
       241ms systemd-sysctl.service
       203ms user@1001.service
       180ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b0b007bd\x2d0a70\x2d40b3\x2d888d\x2d1d5d0f695800.swap
       110ms rtkit-daemon.service
       100ms snapd.socket
        89ms systemd-hostnamed.service
        73ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        48ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        42ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        41ms snapd.boot-ok.service
        20ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

Command egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo outputs:

```
0
```

Comment: pls attach the result of these commands to your question `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame`; pls also check `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` - if the last command prints 0 your hardware is not supporting direct virtualization

Comment: what can i do ? I guess the hardware is not supporting direct virtualization. How can it be solved ?

Comment: what is the host system, is it windows?

Comment: your boot times are fine, except for `apt-daily.service` which should level out, or has somethig to do with your network setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a guest system on a host, that does not support hardware virtualisation, in general makes the guest (and host) slow and the whole experience not much fun.

As you are running a windows system with intel-chip this tool might help you to detect if VTx is enabled: https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/processor-utilities-and-programs/intel-processor-identification-utility.html
If it is not enabled you might have the chance to enable it in your BIOS - if not the show is more or less over.

To enhance the performance of your ubuntu-guest install `open-vm-tools` - via `sudo apt install open-vm-tools` - inside your guest.

The `systemd-analyze blame` results you posted, clearly show that `apt-daily.service` is the culprit for your long boot time - this might be a one-time situation especially when there are many updates to fetch.

If this process always needs that long you could disable it via `sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service`- yet I can't recommend this, as it takes care that your package-informations stay up to date and you are informed of updates.

Comment: My host system is windows 10.

Comment: i updated the answer pls check again and report back, thx